How do i use the split function in google sheet and have that function return an empty cell if there is nothing to split
I have a cell, lets say A1 that contains "Cat, Dog, Rat".
In cell B1 i enter the following formula =split(A1, ",",true, false)
The data then spreads across B1:D1 B1 Cat C1 Dog D1 Rat
The problem i have is if cell A1 is empty my formula returns #Value! with the error "function split parameter one should not be empty.
I'm hoping someone can provide a solution to my problem as i am wanting a formula that will split after every comma and return an empty cell where there is no text to split.
Thanks
I have tried the following formula =split(A1, ",",true, false)
It works when there is data to be split but returns an error when there is not..

Wrap your current split formula within iferror() as such:
=iferror(split(A1,", ",))

